# TYPO3 Backend is locked! #1270853884: TYPO3 Fatal Error

Tags: typo3

My TYPO3 Backend is locked after i changed the password (root) in the phpMyAdmin Extension in the backend. After that everything was locked and i get this error: #1270853884: TYPO3 Fatal Error: The current username, password or host was not accepted when the connection to the database was attempted to be established!
But the InstallTool is not locked so can make changes in there.

I searched in the internet for some solution but didn't find anything helpful.

What can i do now?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should not connect your TYPO3-System with the MySQL root user to your specific database. Add a MySQL user that is only privileged to the needed TYPO3 database.

You can edit your database credentials within the TYPO3 Install Tool without being connected to the database.
The database connection credentials will be stored in:

- TYPO3 4.x: typo3conf/localconf.php
- TYPO3 6.x and later: typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a corrupt innodb file. The table "tx_realurl_urlcache" was the reason. To solve the problem i just truncated this table and restarted mysql. After the restart everything worked again.

In detail:
Because the topics about changing typo3 config did not help me i checked the systems syslog file and found out the mysql system printed a lot of errors. Especially the entry "InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed" helped me finding out what my problem was.
By checking the database sizes i found out that the size of my typo3-database was very large (more than 1.5 GB). So i checked which tables use the space. The biggest one was tx_realurl_urlcache which used more than 1 GB. Because this is just a cache-table i truncated it and restarted the mysql service. This solved the problem.